# Identify column and row headers in excel with python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with multiple tabs, each with possibly multiple tables in them. There are also 'junk' information I want to ignore between tables. Something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvL6a.png)

What I do know is the row headers are always in one column. is there a way to locate the row and column headers (find which rows /columns they are in) efficiently?

the space between tables may not be NaN

I've tried finding the % of cells that's not NaN and deem the first rows with high % of data filled after one or more rows with low % of data filled to be headers. This is very inefficient and requires itering through the tables a lot. I'm trying to find a more efficient approach.